# Computation of integral $\int_{\rho} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let $a,b$ be complex number and  $|a| < r < |b|$, compute.

$\int_{\rho} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)}$

where $\rho$ is the circle with radius $r$ and the usual orientation.

I've tried the common path $\int_{\rho} \frac{dz}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{rie^{i \theta} d\theta}{(re^{i \theta} -a)(re^{i \theta}-b)}$ but in this point I don't know how use the $r$

Answer (score 1):

By [residue theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) the integral is
$$
2\pi i\text {Res}_{z=a}\frac1 {(z-a)(z-b)}=\frac {2\pi i}{a-b},
$$
since only the pole $z=a $ is inside the integration contour.